# Hibernate: @ManyToOne, @OneToMany gives nulls in result

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have java app (Spring + Hibernate) and mySql DB.
*Spring: 5.0.2

Hibernate: 5.2.12.*

There are two entities Student and Lesson. They are in relatioship: one student to many lessons (foreign key in lessons table).
Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@XmlRootElement
public class Student implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "student_id")
   private String studentId;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "studentId")
   private Collection<Lesson> lessonCollection;

   // ...<other fields and some code>...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lessons")
@XmlRootElement
public class Lesson implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "lesson_id")
   private String lessonId;

   @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id")
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private Student studentId;

   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "number")
   private int number;

   // ...<other fields and some code>...
}
```

In DB all fields for Students and Lessons are filled.

I can successfully select all students with Criteria API.
But when i select lessons (one/all) i have Hibernate exception:
**org.hibernate.Property.AccessException: Null value was assigned to a property [class org.Lesson.number] of primitive type setter of org.Lesson.number.**

If i change field 'number' to Integer (nullable), then i get such result:
**[null, null, null]**.
Making request with HQL gives the same result.

Can someone give advice? What wrong with entities and their relationship?
Thanx in advance!

UPD:
code for getting result:

```
public List<E> getAll() throws SQLException {
   CriteriaBuilder builder = curSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<? extends E> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(daoType);
   criteriaQuery.from(daoType);
   Query query = curSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
   try {
        System.out.println(query.getResultList());
   } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new SQLException(e.getMessage()); // that's where it's fire
   }
}
```

Result must be something like
**[org.Lesson[lessonId=1], org.Lesson[lessonId=2], org.Lesson[lessonId=3]]**

UPD2:
**Exception:**

> àïð 02, 2018 4:38:18 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain
>   doDefaultLogging org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Null value was
>   assigned to a property [class org.Lesson.number] of primitive type
>   setter of org.Lesson.number; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a
>   property [class org.Lesson.number] of primitive type setter of
>   org.Lesson.number     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:267)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Null
>   value was assigned to a property [class org.Lesson.number] of
>   primitive type setter of org.Lesson.number; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a
>   property [class org.Lesson.number] of primitive type setter of
>   org.Lesson.number     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getAll(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.service.LessonServiceImpl.getAll(LessonServiceImpl.java:64)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.getAll(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.src.LessonWorkerImpl.getTasks(LessonWorkerImpl.java:155)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null
>   value was assigned to a property [class org.Lesson.number] of
>   primitive type setter of org.Lesson.number    at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:47)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:709)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:205)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4707)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1152)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1011)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:384)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
>     at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)  at
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
>     at org.dao.GenericDaoImpl.getAll(GenericDaoImpl.java:90)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>     ... 60 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not
>   set int field org.kvant.suz.utils.data.db.domain.Task.executingStatus
>   to null value     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:80)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)  at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:41)
>     ... 90 more

Comment: Post your code, including the statement displaying the results. Tell precisely what you expect the result to be, and what it actually is. Also, please rename `studentId` to `student`. It's a studen, not a student ID.

Comment: Already updated post

Comment: **including the statement displaying the results. Tell precisely what you expect the result to be, and what it actually is**. Don't catch Throwable. Let the exception propagate, and post its stack trace if you have an exception.

Comment: Already updated post

Comment: I thought you already figured out what to do to fix this exception: a primitive int number can't possibly contain null, so if the column is nullable, the type should be Integer. If there should never be a null in this column, then a not null constraint should be added to the column, to make that impossible, and the data should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, it's all obvious. All the fields and columns correspond to what you are talking about (IDE took care of this, entities were made by wizards). In particular, the problem field 'number' not nullable. I have a suspicion that this is somehow related to the relationship between entities.

Comment: Situation is that Hibernate returns data with null in all fields.

Answer (score 2):

By default `@OneToMany` `FetchType` is `Lazy` . So that it will not be loaded. Change your mapping as shown below. Note: `FetchType` is specified as `Eager`.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "studentId",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   private Collection<Lesson> lessonCollection;
```

`getLessonCollection` will return the proxy object which will be having the load data of the actual object.

Comment: Big thanx. But... you wrote: "Note: FetchType is specified as Eager." and in you snippet is "fetch=FetchType.LAZY". Where is the true?

Comment: oh sorry.. `FetchType.Eager` i mean